# Commutativity and associativity of convolution in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g:R^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ measurable functions and the convolution is defined by :

$*: L^1(R^n)\times L^1(R^n) \rightarrow L^1(R^n)$

$(f * g)(x)=\int_{R^n} f(x-t)g(t) dt$. To prove the commutativity I can make a change of variables $x-t=y$ but in the case of $\mathbb R$.

In more dimension is the same thing?

Comment: Yes, the same thing.